# innerHTML not adding html content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, innerhtml

I believe I almost have this working. I have a footer already, but when the button is clicked it slides down along with it's contents. After it slides down, I have used javascript to remove that footer and it's contents and I have created another footer element. I have appended it to include a div. When I check the inspector element it shows the new footer and the empty div exists. However, when I add the innerHTML to the id of the div, it does not populate it with the code. Here is the code for the javascript:

```
var slide = document.getElementById('slide');
var info = document.getElementsByClassName('info');
var input = document.getElementById('input');
var footer = document.getElementById('footer');
var addFooter = document.createElement('footer');
var newFooterContent = '<div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2"><input type="text" class="form-control move-right" size="105" placeholder="Say &ldquo;Hello&rdquo; or whatever else is on your mind"> </div> <div class="col-md-2"> <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button> </div>'



$( document ).ready(function() {
    $( "#hidePic" ).click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $( "#slide" ).slideToggle( "fast", function() {
            footer.parentNode.removeChild(footer);
            document.body.appendChild(addFooter);
            addFooter.appendChild(input);
            input.addInnerHTML = newFooterContent;
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: is it because you use addInnerHTML instead of innerHTML?

Comment: And if you're using jQuery then why not `input.html(newFooterContent)` among other things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
input.addInnerHTML = newFooterContent;
```

with

```
input.innerHTML = newFooterContent;
```

and it should work

Comment: That worked in the sense that when I check the inspector element it shows all that content is now in the new footer section, however - none of it shows anywhere on the page. Is that because I used jQuery to slide down the original footer (even though I deleted the old footer tag prior to creating a new one?)

Comment: If you see the content inside of the inspector and not on the screen, then you have a styling issue - some CSS rule prevents you from seeing the content. It can be many things, from display: none, to position: absolute with coordinates outside of the screen. jQuery shouldn't be the problem, though.